# Why is the BING basemap in ArcView different from the one on http://www.bing.com/maps/

Tags: arcgis-desktop, bing-maps, resolution

The quality of the original Bing imagery on the Bing Website is much higher. How can I get it into ArcMap? I read, that the ArcMap imagery BaseLayer is based on Bing service!

South of Ouagadougou (Burkina Faso):

ArcMap Basemap:
[image: ArcGIS imagery baselayer]

Same region on Bing Website:
[image: Bing Website]

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS doesn't use Bing Maps as imagery basemap since December 31 2013. If you want to use Bing Maps in ArcGIS, you must [purchase a license key from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx) (As far as I know it's extremely expensive). See [this link](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9&_ga=1.219302555.324331202.1405496576) to see the sources Esri uses for its imagery basemap. You should expect a 1 m resolution for rural places in Africa.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. This is a quiet logical explanation. Accidentally I found a free WMS-Server loading the BING imagery which works for QGIS. I should be able to load it in ArcMap too I guess...        http://osm.geobretagne.fr/gwc01/service/wms?

Comment: The license isn't that expensive. That's just a bad excuse for not making the maps available by default anymore.